Matplotlib's `line.set_data_3d()` is slower upon reloading the graph
I'm making a website in which users can input one NBA player and get an animation of their shots. The code is working properly, but when I load another NBA player (or the same NBA player the second time), the Matplotlib animation works more slowly.
For example, if I go to the URL 127.0.0.1:5000/?nbaplayer=playerA, the animation will take 20 seconds to load, but then if I go to URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/?nbaplayer=playerA again, the animation will take 30 seconds. Another time, it will take 40 seconds, and so on.
Specifically, the line.set_data_3d() takes up more time than before, which I have timed. I've attached the relevant code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from website.animator import *

matplotlib.use('agg')
views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    args = request.args
    if len(args) == 2:
        ...
        walks = [] #walks will be a 100 x 3 array
        for x,y in zip(player_shotchart['LOC_X'], player_shotchart['LOC_Y']):
            walks.append(getParabola(-y, -x))
        lines = [ax.plot([], [], [])[0] for _ in walks]
        num_steps = 30 * int(np.log(len(walks))) + 1
        
        #The problem here is that ani loads more slowly when reloading
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            fig, update_lines, num_steps, fargs=(walks, lines), interval=30, repeat = False)
        ani_saved = ani.to_jshtml()

        return render_template("base2.html", playerName = args['nbaplayer'], playerSZN = args['nbaseason'], rendered_anim = ani_saved)

And, here's my update_lines function. For context, walks is an 100 x 3 array.
def update_lines(num, walks, lines):    
    for line, walk in zip(lines, walks):
        line.set_data_3d(walk[num:num+3, :].T)
    return lines

I've tried using fig.clf() and fig.cla() in order to clear the axes and completely refresh the figure. Additionally, I've also tried clearing each of the lines by doing line.set_data_3d(np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])), in another animation, update_lines2.
However, none of these seem to make a difference, as the individual times of line.set_data_3d seems to keep increasing. I've even tried clearing cookies and site data, but it doesn't work. I'm essentially animating multiple parabolas at once, so there might be a possible improvement and workaround with blitting, so how do I animate multiple lines at once with blitting?
I would like to go inside line.set_data_3d to see where exactly the time is going but there is no definition or declaration found in VSCode.

have you tried plt.close(fig) right after ani_saved = ani.to_jshtml()?

Yeah, and I also tried plt.close('all') but there is no impact.

YES! Figured out the solution!

Please do share the solution here. It's ok to answer your own question if it worked. Then we have the solution in case anyone in the future is looking to solve this.

Here is a solution that, at least for me, does not result in a slower re-run of the players. I have also chosen to do this in VS Code and I have chsoen the following structure for my project:
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── base2.html

where app.py is given by
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, render_template, request

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

def getParabola():
    theta_initial = np.pi / 3
    x_i = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    y_i = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    z_i = 0
    x_range, y_range = np.linspace(x_i, 0, 30), np.linspace(y_i, 0, 30)
    t_range = -np.sqrt(np.square(x_range) + np.square(y_range))

    a_poly = (t_range[0] * np.tan(theta_initial) + 1) / (t_range[0] ** 2)
    b_poly = -np.tan(theta_initial) - 2 / t_range[0]
    c_poly = 1
    z_range = a_poly * t_range ** 2 + b_poly * t_range + c_poly
    parabolic_coord = np.concatenate((x_range[:, None], y_range[:, None], z_range[:, None]), axis=1)
    return parabolic_coord

walks = [getParabola() for i in range(250)]

def update_lines(num, walks, lines):
    for line, walk in zip(lines, walks):
        line.set_data(walk[:num, 0], walk[:num, 1])
        line.set_3d_properties(walk[:num, 2])  
    return lines

@views.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    try:
        args = request.args
        print(f"Received args: {args}")  
        if 'nbaplayer' in args and 'nbaseason' in args:
            nbaplayer = args['nbaplayer']
            nbaseason = args['nbaseason']
            print(f"Player: {nbaplayer}, Season: {nbaseason}")  

            player_shotchart = {'LOC_X': np.random.randn(100), 'LOC_Y': np.random.randn(100)} 

            walks = []
            for x, y in zip(player_shotchart['LOC_X'], player_shotchart['LOC_Y']):
                walks.append(getParabola())

            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
            lines = [ax.plot([], [], [])[0] for _ in walks]
            num_steps = 30 * int(np.log(len(walks))) + 1

            ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
                fig, update_lines, num_steps, fargs=(walks, lines), interval=30, repeat=False)
            ani_saved = ani.to_jshtml()

            plt.close(fig)  

            return render_template("base2.html", playerName=nbaplayer, playerSZN=nbaseason, rendered_anim=ani_saved)
        else:
            print("Missing parameters")  
            return "Invalid parameters. Please provide 'nbaplayer' and 'nbaseason' in the query string.", 400
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during request processing: {e}")
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        return "Internal Server Error", 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.register_blueprint(views)
        app.run(debug=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during Flask app startup: {e}")
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()



and base2.html looks like
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NBA Player Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Animation for {{ playerName }} - {{ playerSZN }}</h1>
    <div>
        {{ rendered_anim|safe }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

when http://127.0.0.1:5000/?nbaplayer=LeBronJames&nbaseason=2023 is run, I get (here it is of course mock data)

Reloading or re-running it works at the same speed.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to solve the problem. I've ran your code for the lines, but when I try with parabolic data, it still runs too slowly. Maybe there's a limit with Matplotlib, but it doesn't seem so.
Please try with walks = [getParabola() for i in range(250)] and use the following function for getParabola(): https://www.online-python.com/FTcoLnxN16. You may need to use matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128 here. For me, it took several more seconds to make the animation after reloading each time.

@YashJain I updated my answer with the right getParabolic and the walks. I works fine for me. Test it. Let me know if you still face the same issue.

Issue still persists. On the first run, it took ~17 seconds. On the second run, it took upwards of 20 seconds on multiple runs.

Weird. For me it takes under 10 seconds both runs.

I also don't think there's any difference in line.set_data and line.set_3d_properties as compared to line.set_data_3d.
I don't mind the little extra time but the problem is that when I load a player with a lot of shots (say LeBron James) first, and then load playerB with not many shots, the time it takes to load playerB's animation becomes 20 or so seconds more because of LeBron's animation.

For a new player, all you have to change is the lines/parabolas when loading up another page. This is why I thought that keeping the non-changing shapes (basketball hoop/floor/rim/etc.) so I wouldn't have to waste time in defining them again was the proper solution.
However, retaining the same axes creates a slowdown for some reason, which I don't know why, even if there is nothing on the plot besides the animation. Nevertheless, the solution to this is to redefine the axes for each time you go to the page.
For example:
def init_base(ax = ax):
    #Populate your plot here, but not elsewhere

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET"])
def home():
    ...
    #Define new figure and axes here, and populate these elsewhere
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d', computed_zorder = False)

    #Initialize ax in 'init_base'
    init_base(ax)
    ...
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            fig, update_lines, num_steps, fargs=(walks, lines), interval=30, repeat = False)
    ani_saved = ani.to_jshtml()

    return render_template("base2.html", playerName = args['nbaplayer'], playerSZN = args['nbaseason'], rendered_anim = ani_saved)

